# What is the observed value of the test statistic?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, p-value

Really struggling with this practice quiz question. Could anybody walk me through how to get an answer?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [test statistic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_statistic) is
$$\frac{\hat{p}-p_0}{\sqrt{\dfrac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}}}\sim N(0,1).$$
Plug your values $\hat{p}=30/191$, $p_0=0.1$, $n=191$ and get the **observed value of the test statistic**.

Comment: Wait I plugged it all in and got it wrong - do I need to do anything with the ~N(0,1) ?